# Strange results when using glGetInternalformativ

Tags: opengl, nvidia

I've just switched from an AMD gpu to a Nvidia GPU (331.82 windows driver) and I am somewhat surprised by the results I get when using `glGetInternalformativ`. For starters, when I query a texture format for `GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_FORMAT`, most seem to return 0. A few examples are `GL_RGB8`, `GL_SRGB8`, `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8`, `GL_RGB32F`, `GL_COMPRESSED_SIGNED_RG_RGTC2`. A few examples that return something other than 0 are `GL_RGBA8`, `GL_R32UI`, `GL_RGB9_E5`, `GL_RGB10_A2`, `GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_BPTC_UNSIGNED_FLOAT`. Is this a bug?

Something else that seems odd to me is that when checking `GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_TYPE` the formats `GL_RGB8`, `GL_SRGB8` and `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` all return `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`, but `GL_RBGA8` returns `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV`.

As requested, the code I am using:

```
void print_tex_format_info(GLenum internalformat)
{
    GLuint pformat, format, type;

    glGetInternalformativ(GL_TEXTURE_2D, internalformat, GL_INTERNALFORMAT_PREFERRED, 1, &pformat);
    glGetInternalformativ(GL_TEXTURE_2D, internalformat, GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_FORMAT, 1, &format);
    glGetInternalformativ(GL_TEXTURE_2D, internalformat, GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_TYPE, 1, &type);

    printf("IF [%s]\nPF [%s]\nXF [%s]\nTP [%s]\n\n",
        ogl_EnumToString(internalformat),
        ogl_EnumToString(pformat),
        ogl_EnumToString(format),
        ogl_EnumToString(type)
    );
}

print_tex_format_info(GL_RGB8);
print_tex_format_info(GL_RGBA8);
print_tex_format_info(GL_SRGB8);
etc
```

`ogl_EnumToString` uses a giant switch to convert a GLenum to the equivalent string. It returns `GL_ZERO` which is also the same as `GL_NONE`. The default case is not 0, so it's not a case of `ogl_EnumToString` not recognizing the enum or anything.

Comment: **0** is also known as `GL_NONE`, which Internal Format queries are allowed to return if the texture format is not accepted for a call to `glTexImage2D (...)` or `glTexSubImage2D (...)`. It will return one or more non-zero values if it has a preferred format to use for pixel transfer (i.e. the proverbial *"fast path"*). Assuming your target is not `GL_RENDERBUFFER`, those should actually all be valid and have a preferred format. Can you display the actual code you are using to query these? As for the preferred type for RGBA, this is pretty common wisdom - it is an endian preference for GPUs.

Comment: By that, I mean if you use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` then pixel transfer will hit the fast path. You are using a power-of-two aligned pixel size so if you combine that with the proper byte order the driver can do a direct copy. RGB8 is a disgusting 24-bit format which suffers alignment issues (or at least it would, if most drivers did not automatically replace this format with a 32-bit format internally).

Comment: @andon I've updated with some code. As you said, all those formats should be valid for `glTexImage2D`, so I don't understand why it is doing this.

Comment: Side note: You do realize you are passing the address of an unsigned integer to a function that expects a pointer to a signed integer? It hardly matters in this case because the stored value will always be a `GLenum` (which is unsigned), but a strict C++ compiler will give you a warning / error for doing this.

Comment: @andon Noted. As far as the endianness goes, my confusion surrounds the fact that RGBA and sRGBA are different. That doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Considering that this is almost certainly an implementation bug, what is the best way to submit this to Nvidia?

Comment: As with all bug reports to driver teams, they generally want a very small working example program. In this case the example can be extraordinarily simple, there is no window event loop to setup or anything. Just write a few lines of code to get a render context, and then insert the function you wrote. They might not appreciate this gargantuan switch function to convert enum values to strings though. Printing the hexadecimal constants might be friendlier. You have already illustrated in your question here, the expected output and behavior on a competitor's product, so that is a very good start.